# What is Redelivery and Rollback in Apache Camel?

Tags: apache, apache-camel, spring-camel

I am new to apache camel and couldn't understand the difference between Redelivery and Rollback.. Could you please help me understand this ?

Comment: redelivery = something failed, but try again. Rollback = something failed dont try again, but stop routing and fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redelivery = something failed, but try again.
Rollback = something failed dont try again, but stop routing and fail.

Error handling can be a complex area to understand and master with Camel. My book Camel in Action 2nd ed has a full chapter on this subject.

There is also some docs online with some details (although not as elegant written and fully up to date - our website and docs on Apache Camel is currently undergoing a transition to a new modern look and feel): http://camel.apache.org/error-handling-in-camel.html

Comment: I got your point. but what does handled(true) work in the context of error-handling ? I mean what if we don't specify handled(true) ?

Comment: handled = true means handle the exception by catching it, and then stop routing and (optionally route/process the message alternatively, for example to prepare a response message with some error details etc).